# Run a dynamic number of shell provisioners on the same VM in Vagrant without changing the Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, yaml, vagrantfile

I am writing a Vagrantfile to set up a VM. There are some config parameters that I do not want to hardcode in the Vagrantfile, such as Memory and number of CPUs. As a consequence, I'm using a YAML file which gets loaded in the Vagrantfile to store these config parameters. One thing that is stored in the YAML file is the list of shell provisioner scripts to run. For instance:

```
---
machine_config:
  mem: 2048
  cpus: 2
  provisioners:
    -name: shell-script-1
     path: <path-to-shell-script-1>
    -name: shell-script-2
     path: <path-to-shell-script-2>
---
```

The number of provisioners is not known a priori: in the YAML above there are two, but it's only an example. I'd like to have a Vagrantfile which can run all of the provisioners in the YAML file. What I mean is that I want to be able to add/remove provisioners to the YAML file without touching the Vagrantfile, yet the Vagrantfile should correctly run all of the provisioners in the YAML file. I searched on Google and there are plenty of examples on how to run the same, hardcoded provisioners on a dynamic number of VMs, but could find none for my problem.

What I'd like to do, written in pseudo-vagrantfile syntax, is:

```
require "yaml"

current_dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
yaml_config = YAML.load_file("#{current_dir}/machine_config.yaml")
machine_config = yaml_config["machine_config"]
additional_scripts = machine_config["provisioners"]

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = <vm-box-to-use>

  for each item $script in additional_scripts do 
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: $script["path"] 
  end

end
```

where machine_config.yaml is a YAML file like the one in the first example of this question, and $script is a variable that at every iteration of the loop holds a provisioner among those described in machine_config.yaml. As a last remark, I know nothing about Ruby and Ruby's syntax (maybe to someone with that knowledge the answer to my question is trivial, but I couldn't find it by googling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work

```
require "yaml"

current_dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
yaml_config = YAML.load_file("#{current_dir}/machine_config.yaml")
machine_config = yaml_config["machine_config"]

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "<vm-box-to-use>"

  machine_config["provisioners"].each do |script|
    config.vm.provision "shell", name: script['name'], path: script['path']
  end

end
```